# ubuntu found printer but Libre Office says "could not start printer please check your printer configuration" Brother HL-5450 printer

Tags: printing

I installed ubuntu from the iso image from ubuntu, it found my brother printer. The app "hardware probe" printed out my hardware but Libre Office says "could not start printer please check your printer configuration". Very Top of the screen says printer canceled on cups printer.
Printer set up found cups-brf-printer saved, restarted program but I get the same error.
Printer is a Brother HL-5450DN Ubuntu was installed 3 days ago and updated and is on a LAN.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: somehow someway the real printer driver finally showed up>

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late to answer your question, but my answer can help other people encountering with this issue.

**Solution:**
Navigate to http://localhost:631/admin and add your printer there. Just make sure you have the required drivers for your printer installed.